# Output did not show on my device (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While I run these codes, it shows no error in my logcat, but  when I click on text 'New Member? REGISTER', it did not display the register page, it goes back to the splash screen instead on my device.
I think it is most probably the id problem but I am not sure which exactly caused this problem.

My activity_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Login"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_logo"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:transitionName="logo_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_new"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
    android:text="Hi, Welcome Back!"
    android:transitionName="logo_text"
    android:textColor="#ff8e88"
    android:textSize="40sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="logo_desc"
    android:text="Sign in to continue"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:transitionName="user_tran"
        android:hint="Username">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:transitionName="password_tran"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <CheckBox
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remember Me" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="Forget Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ff8e88"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:transitionName="button_tran"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
        android:text="New Member? REGISTER"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:transitionName="login_register_tran"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Login.java:

```
  public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

  Button callRegister, login_btn;
  ImageView image;
  TextView logoText, sloganText;
  TextInputLayout username,password;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.
    FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callRegister = findViewById(R.id.register_screen);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image_logo);
    logoText = findViewById(R.id.logo_name);
    sloganText = findViewById(R.id.slogan_name);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_btn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

    callRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);

            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[7];

            pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(image,"logo_logo");
            pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String>(logoText,"logo_text");
            pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String>(sloganText,"logo_desc");
            pairs[3] = new Pair<View,String>(username,"user_tran");
            pairs[4] = new Pair<View,String>(password,"password_tran");
            pairs[5] = new Pair<View,String>(login_btn,"button_tran");
            pairs[6] = new Pair<View,String>(callRegister,"login_register_tran");

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptions options = 
            ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Login.this,pairs);
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

My activity_register.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Register"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#fff"
 android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:transitionName="logo_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_new"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:transitionName="logo_text"
    android:textColor="#ff8e88"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slogan_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register to start"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Type"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guardian"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#ff8e88"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Already have an account? LOGIN"
    android:background="#00000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Register.java:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you try remove `            ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Login.this,pairs);` and see if it works? Also makesure your device or Virtual Machine is higher than Lollipop 21

Answer (score 0):

There was some problems within your code. Your naming on the id from xml to your java were inconsistent. for example:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/logo_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
android:text="Hi, Welcome Back!"
android:transitionName="logo_text"
android:textColor="#ff8e88"
android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

notice your naming in the id `android:id="@+id/logo_name"` then in your java file you had it correct but you defined `slogan` as an id, but you do not have an xml named `slogan` so what i did was created a new project and replicated everything. So I am using a little different naming convention between classes but it still shows the differences.

> MainActivity.java  aka Login.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button callRegister, login_btn;
ImageView image;
TextView logoText, sloganText;
TextInputLayout username,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.
            FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    callRegister = findViewById(R.id.register_screen);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image_logo);
    logoText = findViewById(R.id.logo_name);
    sloganText = findViewById(R.id.logo_name);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_btn = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    callRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[7];

            pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(image,"logo_logo");
            pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String>(logoText,"logo_text");
            pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String>(sloganText,"logo_desc");
            pairs[3] = new Pair<View,String>(username,"user_tran");
            pairs[4] = new Pair<View,String>(password,"password_tran");
            pairs[5] = new Pair<View,String>(login_btn,"button_tran");
            pairs[6] = new Pair<View,String>(callRegister,"login_register_tran");

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptions options =
                        ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,pairs);
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

where you had the `slogan` for the the view id... for sake of showing i changed it to the `logo` where ever your slogan text is name it with an id then reference it there in the java file.

You also miss identified your other buttons such as the login button. I fixed several errors, and then ran the project and when i clicked on register it worked perfectly.

Check to make sure you have everything named properly and referenced properly. also compare the fix, as to yours and then try it and see if it works. Remember where you have the `Login` I use `MainActivity`